# mx records issues with plesk

Tags: ubuntu, email, dns, plesk

Hi I have two domains they both have a A records to the same ubuntu server with plesk.

One of the domains uses a mail Server on the same ubuntu plesk server. The second domain has its dns mx record to a different hoster.

Now when I send a mail from the Mail which is hosted on the ubuntu plesk server to the second (external server) I got an error message.

What I think is the mail is transferred internally on the server and there is an error. I set the DNS records in plesk for to the external mx ...

what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Error Message:

Ihre Nachricht hat einige oder alle Empfänger nicht erreicht.

```
  Betreff:  test von Felix
  Gesendet am:  24.09.2018 19:23
```

Folgende(r) Empfänger kann/können nicht erreicht werden:

```
  'info@domain.com' am 24.09.2018 19:23
        Serverfehler: "550 5.1.1 <info@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table"'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the error(s) you get.

Comment: added the error abvoe sorry for missing